# Get Key of nested Array from Flatlist

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a flatlist that is receiving a friendsArray with the following data structure...

[image]

I have a modal that has an onPress function, with that onPress i'd like to get the value of this key. I have the following Code, but usually this code provides me with the key of whatever i just selected in the flatlist... i'd like to get the key of the item selected one level deeper, how do i do this?

Here is App.js

```
onFriendChatPress = key => {
   let friend = this.state.friendsArray.find(game => { return game.key === key })
}


render(){
return{
    <View>
        <FriendsModal
            onChatPress={() => this.onChatPress()}
            onClosePress={() => this.closeModal()}
            onFriendPress={() => this.onFriendPress()}
            onFriendChatPress={() => this.onFriendChatPress()}
            selGame={this.state.selGame}
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            selGame={this.state.selGame}
        />
    </View>
}
```

Here is FlatList in the FriendsModal

```
      <FlatList
           style={styles.flatList}
           data={this.props.selGame.friends}
           horizontal={true}
           renderItem={(info) => (
                       <ModalProfileCard
                               displayName={info.item.displayName}
                               image={info.item.image}
                               onFriendPress={() => this.props.onFriendPress(info.item.key)}
                               onFriendChatPress={() => this.props.onFriendChatPress(info.item.key)}
                        />
                       )
                      }
              />
```

Here is the Card in the modal

```
function modalProfileCard(props) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onFriendsPress} style={styles.friendInfo}>
                <Image style={styles.profImage} source={{ uri: props.image }} />
                <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>{props.displayName}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={props.onFriendChatPress}>
                {buttonText}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View >
    )
}
```

Comment: Share your flatlist code and onPress where you are opening modal

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani - i've added more detail that you've requested, any thoughts?

Comment: So confusing in your code, in renderItem, shouldn't you use info.displayName instead of info.item.displayNam?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani - info.item.displayName works, info.displayName is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Though I understand is

> In renderItem, shouldn't you use info.displayName instead of info.item.displayNam? and so on ..

There is also a parent FlatList? You are saving the selected game in state as selGame right? You can save it's index also and can pass to child component so It would be easy to find the selected game's key.